# Axios and diacritic characters

Tags: node.js, axios

This API I need to hit has french accents and diacritic characters such as: oe

For the accents, there's no issues at all (I encodeURI/decodeURI using jS).

However that specific diacritic character straight up breaks the axios get request.

I'm looking for a solution which doesn't involves refactoring the whole code using fetch instead of axios (some options I'm using are very useful, such as limiting the number of requests par seconds etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Skip your french characters via **/** and use double quotes  **" "**  .this would help in your api routing

Comment: The character needs to be sent, because they are stored so.

Comment: Code example please for your issue